# What kind of an effect does writing just logging code in Catch block without handling the behavior, have on program performance?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I am working on re factoring a code base.  The code snippet in one of the places is as follows.

```
try
{
    doSomething();
}
catch(Exception exe)
{
    ---Logging code---
}
```

I understand that the catch block must contain the code to control the program flow in case an exception occurs in doSomething();.  But, I want to know, the performance impact if the above code if left as is.

Comment: In short? Nothing.  Logging an exception is often the extent of what's put in a catch block

Comment: What would be the (/your) alternative to the way the code is now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some performance impact while using try catch. But they are so minor that you should not bother about them.

Only thing that you should care is to avoid try catch block directly in loops. But when you need them, then you need them and they must be in the code.

Comment: @Chill: Are you sure about that?  The bytecode offsets of protected ranges and their handlers should already be a part of the VM's internal method representation.  Each entry in the VM's internal stack state must contain a pointer back to that method data.  Maintaining a separate table for exception handlers seems redundant.

Comment: @MikeStrobel You are right. I deleted my comment. Exceptions take a long time when the stack trace needs to get built up, but it only needs to search the stack and reference class definitions to figure out where to throw the exception. The performance hit comes from the fact that the compiler can't optimize the loops as easily.

Answer (score 0):

The catch block can do whatever you want it to do.  You can have it do something with program flow if you wish.  You can have it wrap the exception and throw a new one.  You can have it log a message.  In my applications, I frequently log messages so I can run reports / gather statistics on the logs at a later time, and then continue on.

If you just log a message, and then continue on, there is obviously a performance impact because you have to actually log the message (this is relatively minor).  How much of an impact depends on your logging framework.

Like the poster above says, loops will multiply the performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any performance penalty for executing code within a `try` block.  There may be a (negligible) impact from an added branch instruction if the method continues past the end of the `try/catch/finally` block.  The runtime performance impact would mostly be seen in cases where an exception is actually caught and handled.  There is some overhead in unwinding the stack to the correct location and selecting the correct handler(s).

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is to catch generic `Exception` that is often a bad idea.